# How should a container running in network mode bridge communicate with another container running in host mode?

Tags: docker, consul, docker-network

My particular use case is with `consul` running with `--net=host`. This is what the [consul docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/) recommends. On the same instance are other containers running using the default `bridge` network.

I can reach the consul container on it exposed port using localhost:8500 from the host machine. But this address does not work from inside the bridge mode containers.

What is the recommended way to achieve communication from the bridge mode containers to the consul container running in host mode?

Comment: You can use the `ip` of the host, or the FQDN of it.

Comment: The host ip is 127.0.0.1. How do I get the FQDN?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback ip, your host is supposed to have a private ip or public ip, either one will work.

Comment: You can try to figure out your network address by running `ifconfig` and get your IP address from there, or run `hostname -I` to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Containers in bridge network can access bridge gateway running on the host. For default bridge network, bridge gateway is usually 172.17.0.1. We can do like this:

```
docker run -ti --add-host consul:172.17.0.1 ubuntu:latest bash
```

Now we can access consul service using "consul" assuming consul is started from host machine on docker0 IP(172.17.0.1)